# How to handle the kinect camera's vertical movement while using amcl?

Tags: navigation, kinect, openni-camera, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the [amcl page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl):

> An implementation detail: on receipt of the first laser scan, amcl looks up the transform between the laser's frame and the base frame (~base_frame_id), and latches it forever. So amcl cannot handle a laser that moves with respect to the base.

Since the kinect camera has a motor that moves it up and down, would this cause a problem? Is there an accepted way yo deal with this? Should I just modify the pointcloud_to_laserscan node to somehow compensate for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9695/how-to-handle-the-kinect-camera%27s-vertical-movement-while-using-amcl?/) by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1033 on 2011-04-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My solution (with help) for a tilting Kinect laserscan was to develop a nodelet that transforms the pointcloud referenced to base_link (or base_footprint) and then converts it to a laserscan using the full robot height as the elevation filter. This is all documented in the "pointcloud to laserscan with transform?" question. Search Kinect or turtlebot tags.

Now I am working on panning the Kinect to produce a full 180 degree laserscan, as the 60 degree field of view of the Kinect is limiting for AMCL and map making. Both of these depend on a functional tf tree that includes the Kinect pan/tilt mechanism and is updated from the hardware interface program.

---

Originally posted by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) with karma: 856 on 2011-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0